# Find all combinations of two-character letters/digits, similar to jot(1) for numbers

Tags: shell, perl, awk, scripting

I'd like to get all combinations of two-character lower-case Latin letters and digits in shell.  Starting with `00`, …, `0a` and ending with `z0`, …, `zz`.

If this was just the single digits, it could have been accomplished with [`jot(1)`](http://mdoc.su/-/jot.1) with `jot 10 0`.

Turns out, just the single-character letters are also possible with `jot -w %c 26 a`.

I guess I could combine the above myself with nested explicit `for` loops, doing a total of four `jot` calls (two in each loop), and mixing it all together, but is there a better solution?

Requirements: must work on *BSD and OS X; `jot`, `awk` and `perl` are available.

Answer (score 4):

Combining the answers by [*jenesaisquoi*](/users/2415684/jenesaisquoi) and [*David C. Rankin*](/users/3422102/david-c-rankin), the shortest solution would appear to require `bash` ([`tcsh`](http://ports.su/shells/tcsh) and OpenBSD's [`ksh`](http://mdoc.su/o/ksh.1) don't support `echo {0..9}` expansion), and is as follows:

```
bash -c 'printf "%s\n" {{0..9},{a..z}}{{0..9},{a..z}}.suffix'
```

Of course, if `\n` isn't required, it could be even shorter than above:

```
bash -c 'echo {{0..9},{a..z}}{{0..9},{a..z}}.suffix'
```

---

The next best solution by [*zdim*](/users/4653379/zdim) and optimised by [*ikegami*](/users/589924/ikegami), and the first one that fits requirements, is using perl:

```
perl -E'@w=(0..9,a..z);map{$w=$_;say"$w$_.suffix"for@w}@w;'
```

Comment: @jenesaisquoi it's still a solution, you didn't have to delete your answer!

Comment: No need for three nested loops. Shorter than even bash: `perl -wE'@w=(0..9,a..z);map{$w=$_;say"$w$_.suffix"for@w}@w;'`, It wouldn't call this or your version better than zdim's, though. If it wasn't for the bash version, I'd downvote the answer for unnecessary golfing.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, I was replying to cnst's answer, not your comment. I was saying that I wouldn't call the Perl solution I posted or the Perl solution cnst posted better than zdim's. Needless golfing reduced readability and maintainability. cnst's bash solution is nice, though.

Comment: @ikegami thanks, I've added it; BTW, if an absolute shortest solution is required (golfing style), then bash could still be made the shortest by replacing `printf "%s\n"` with just the `echo`

Answer (score 2):

With Perl

```
perl -wE'@w = (0..9,"a".."z"); say for map { $w=$_; map $w.$_, @w } @w'
```

To also append (`.ext`) to every term

```
perl -wE'@w = (0..9,"a".."z"); say for map { $w=$_; map $w.$_.".ext", @w } @w'
```

Or to optionally pass to the command what suffix to use

```
perl -wE'
    $e=shift//""; $e &&= ".$e";
    @w = (0..9,"a".."z"); say for map { $w=$_; map $w.$_.$e, @w } @w'
```

for invocation `perl -wE'...' suffix`, or omit `suffix` to use the default (empty string here).

A `.` is added before the suffix when it is given, where `$e &&= ...` is `$e && $e = ...`

Comment: cool, `perl -wE'@w = (0..9, "a".."z"); @s = map { $w=$_; map $w.$_, @w } @w; say for @s' | xargs` seems to work, thanks!

Comment: @cnst Right, just simplified -- those indices were remains of another approach

Comment: cool, yes, and if extra prefix/suffix is needed, then change `say` with `say $_, ".suffix"` also works.

Comment: @cnst "_if extra prefix/suffix is needed..._"  -- yes, a nice one --- while if you need a more substiantial transformation can pipe it through a `map` for printing (or through another `map` while producing `@s` if this ends up as a part of a larger script where you need results stored in an array)

Comment: cool, thanks, so, we're getting, like, `perl -wE'@w=(0..9,"a".."z");say"$_.suffix"for map{$w=$_;map$w.$_,@w}@w;' | xargs` in the end now! :-)  The only required space is between `for map`; wonder is there's a way to get rid of it, too! :)

Comment: @cnst Updated to add the suffix (which I didn't realize you'd need), in a couple of ways.  Can be tweaked -- and surely shorted -- if that's needed

Comment: Cool!  BTW, it seems that `for` is optional, provided you add a space or `\n` after the `.ext` suffix (but then you'd also have a trailing space at the very end, too).

Comment: @cnst indeed -- `say` (and `print`) takes a list, so it's OK to give it output of `map`. Except that elements would come out glued together -- unless you add a space (or \n) that is, as you say (or really `say join " ", map ...` -- no trailing space). Also, you can golf it down a little by dropping `-w` (warnings) since then you can do `a..z` (no quotes), can use `undef`s (nothin' comes out), etc.  I didn't realize that trimming it down by chars was of interest:)

Comment: @cnst Updated the last snippet a little.  Btw, elements in lists when printed get in between them what `$,` is; by default nothing.  So with `$,=" ";` one can do `say map...` and elements of the list that `map` puts out are printed with a space between them.  That doesn't reduce byte count though ...

Comment: yeah, thanks, I think it's good!  (the suffix is fixed for my usecase; but that's useful to remember how to handle the args!  nice code for adding the `.` only if the suffix is present, too!)

Comment: @cnst Right, it seemed like you wouldn't need it but I thought it may be good to have that in general.  (Sorry about silly (non-sensical) "comments" that i posted here in the last hour or so -- removed now -- was playing with formatting in comments, trying to figure out how to use Unicode symbols in here ... failed so far .. :(

Comment: @cnst Right, by copying it -- but how do I produce it by U+205D (or as entity, &#8285;) ... perhaps can't

Comment: Just search it, and copy-paste the results — ⁝.  Sadly, entities don't appear to be supported on SO.

Comment: @cnst Yeah, it may be that that's that for comments ... makes it more labor-some :((.   Entities work directly in text, in proper posts (Q/A) (I use things like <sup>&dagger;</sup> quite often)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, if you simply have bash available, you can do it with *brace-expansion* and `printf`, e.g.

```
printf "%s\n" {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}
```

Which essentially just takes the characters `[0-9][a-z]` in side-by-side brace-expansions fed to `printf` to line separate each output.

**Example Output**

```
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
0a
0b
0c
0d
0e
0f
0g
...
zw
zx
zy
zz

(1296 lines)
```

Use `echo` if you want the output space separated.

Comment: Yeah, this basically works in any shell, including tcsh, but it's way too much copy-pasting, plus, can't be sure you didn't make a mistake in your alphabet list!

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box and easily adaptable to any set of characters you care about just by modifying the bracket expression `[[:lower:][:digit:]]` to include your target characters:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    for (asciiNr=0; asciiNr<=127; asciiNr++) {
        char = sprintf("%c", asciiNr)
        if ( char ~ /[[:lower:][:digit:]]/ ) {
            chars[++numChars] = char
        }
    }
    for (i=1; i<=numChars; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=numChars; j++) {
            printf "%s%s%s", chars[i], chars[j], (j<numChars ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 0g 0h 0i 0j 0k 0l 0m 0n 0o 0p 0q 0r 0s 0t 0u 0v 0w 0x 0y 0z
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 1g 1h 1i 1j 1k 1l 1m 1n 1o 1p 1q 1r 1s 1t 1u 1v 1w 1x 1y 1z
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f 2g 2h 2i 2j 2k 2l 2m 2n 2o 2p 2q 2r 2s 2t 2u 2v 2w 2x 2y 2z
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f 3g 3h 3i 3j 3k 3l 3m 3n 3o 3p 3q 3r 3s 3t 3u 3v 3w 3x 3y 3z
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f 4g 4h 4i 4j 4k 4l 4m 4n 4o 4p 4q 4r 4s 4t 4u 4v 4w 4x 4y 4z
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e 5f 5g 5h 5i 5j 5k 5l 5m 5n 5o 5p 5q 5r 5s 5t 5u 5v 5w 5x 5y 5z
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 6g 6h 6i 6j 6k 6l 6m 6n 6o 6p 6q 6r 6s 6t 6u 6v 6w 6x 6y 6z
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 7b 7c 7d 7e 7f 7g 7h 7i 7j 7k 7l 7m 7n 7o 7p 7q 7r 7s 7t 7u 7v 7w 7x 7y 7z
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8a 8b 8c 8d 8e 8f 8g 8h 8i 8j 8k 8l 8m 8n 8o 8p 8q 8r 8s 8t 8u 8v 8w 8x 8y 8z
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 9a 9b 9c 9d 9e 9f 9g 9h 9i 9j 9k 9l 9m 9n 9o 9p 9q 9r 9s 9t 9u 9v 9w 9x 9y 9z
a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 aa ab ac ad ae af ag ah ai aj ak al am an ao ap aq ar as at au av aw ax ay az
b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9 ba bb bc bd be bf bg bh bi bj bk bl bm bn bo bp bq br bs bt bu bv bw bx by bz
c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 ca cb cc cd ce cf cg ch ci cj ck cl cm cn co cp cq cr cs ct cu cv cw cx cy cz
d0 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9 da db dc dd de df dg dh di dj dk dl dm dn do dp dq dr ds dt du dv dw dx dy dz
e0 e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9 ea eb ec ed ee ef eg eh ei ej ek el em en eo ep eq er es et eu ev ew ex ey ez
f0 f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 fa fb fc fd fe ff fg fh fi fj fk fl fm fn fo fp fq fr fs ft fu fv fw fx fy fz
g0 g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6 g7 g8 g9 ga gb gc gd ge gf gg gh gi gj gk gl gm gn go gp gq gr gs gt gu gv gw gx gy gz
h0 h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 h7 h8 h9 ha hb hc hd he hf hg hh hi hj hk hl hm hn ho hp hq hr hs ht hu hv hw hx hy hz
i0 i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 ia ib ic id ie if ig ih ii ij ik il im in io ip iq ir is it iu iv iw ix iy iz
j0 j1 j2 j3 j4 j5 j6 j7 j8 j9 ja jb jc jd je jf jg jh ji jj jk jl jm jn jo jp jq jr js jt ju jv jw jx jy jz
k0 k1 k2 k3 k4 k5 k6 k7 k8 k9 ka kb kc kd ke kf kg kh ki kj kk kl km kn ko kp kq kr ks kt ku kv kw kx ky kz
l0 l1 l2 l3 l4 l5 l6 l7 l8 l9 la lb lc ld le lf lg lh li lj lk ll lm ln lo lp lq lr ls lt lu lv lw lx ly lz
m0 m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8 m9 ma mb mc md me mf mg mh mi mj mk ml mm mn mo mp mq mr ms mt mu mv mw mx my mz
n0 n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 n7 n8 n9 na nb nc nd ne nf ng nh ni nj nk nl nm nn no np nq nr ns nt nu nv nw nx ny nz
o0 o1 o2 o3 o4 o5 o6 o7 o8 o9 oa ob oc od oe of og oh oi oj ok ol om on oo op oq or os ot ou ov ow ox oy oz
p0 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 pa pb pc pd pe pf pg ph pi pj pk pl pm pn po pp pq pr ps pt pu pv pw px py pz
q0 q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 q9 qa qb qc qd qe qf qg qh qi qj qk ql qm qn qo qp qq qr qs qt qu qv qw qx qy qz
r0 r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7 r8 r9 ra rb rc rd re rf rg rh ri rj rk rl rm rn ro rp rq rr rs rt ru rv rw rx ry rz
s0 s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7 s8 s9 sa sb sc sd se sf sg sh si sj sk sl sm sn so sp sq sr ss st su sv sw sx sy sz
t0 t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 ta tb tc td te tf tg th ti tj tk tl tm tn to tp tq tr ts tt tu tv tw tx ty tz
u0 u1 u2 u3 u4 u5 u6 u7 u8 u9 ua ub uc ud ue uf ug uh ui uj uk ul um un uo up uq ur us ut uu uv uw ux uy uz
v0 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 va vb vc vd ve vf vg vh vi vj vk vl vm vn vo vp vq vr vs vt vu vv vw vx vy vz
w0 w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 wa wb wc wd we wf wg wh wi wj wk wl wm wn wo wp wq wr ws wt wu wv ww wx wy wz
x0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 xa xb xc xd xe xf xg xh xi xj xk xl xm xn xo xp xq xr xs xt xu xv xw xx xy xz
y0 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9 ya yb yc yd ye yf yg yh yi yj yk yl ym yn yo yp yq yr ys yt yu yv yw yx yy yz
z0 z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 z6 z7 z8 z9 za zb zc zd ze zf zg zh zi zj zk zl zm zn zo zp zq zr zs zt zu zv zw zx zy zz
```

Comment: Well, I wasn't looking for a Java solution!  (Sorry, couldn't resist.)  Perhaps it wasn't explicit, but, based on existing answers and comments, I'm looking for a one-off short snippet, and although this awk solution is nice at showing how to use awk as a full programming language, it's overly long and complex for the problem at stake; I think even a `jot` solution with two for loops would be simpler (and more maintanable, as everyone knows how to use shell, and integrate logic around it).

Comment: You're welcome to your opinion of course but while this solution is longer than others, it's less complex rather than more because each step is written out explicitly, and it's more trivially extensible to different character lists (try simply adding `%` to the list of chars in each solution), and more portable (it'll work everywhere) and you're wrong in your last statement - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons why.

Comment: This solution being less complex than mere `{{0..9},{a..z}}{{0..9},{a..z}}`?!  Please.  There's also no input from the user at any point here; so, it's unclear why you're linking to the QA about security vulnerabilities of accepting untrusted input in shell.  I suggest you look into the term "overengineering" — it is expressly a part of the original question that the alphabet is limited to `:lower:` and `:digit:`, and there's absolutely no need for extension at any point (of course, it may still help someone else who finds this looking for an entirely different problem)

Comment: Yes explicit loops are less complex than `{{0..9},{a..z}}{{0..9},{a..z}}`, it's just not briefer than it. Also `{0..9},{a..z}` is only `:lower:` and `:digit:` **if** your locale has the same order of characters as the C locale while the solution I posted will work in any locale. That link doesn't just discuss security vulnerabilities it also explains how extremely slow a shell loop (and by extension two nested shell loops!) would be. Writing code that cannot easily be extended is a poor design choice. As I mentioned, though, you're welcome to your opinion.